# My Python GUI doesn't marks all keywords right

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I made a Python GUI, that let's the user input things like in notepad.
Then I added a thread, that checks, if the keyword `input` is found and marks it BLUE.
It marked the `import` keyword, but not the full word... only the 't' at the end.
So I decided to make an output, which prints all colored keywords, and its Beginning `line.char` (the `i` of import)->to the end `line.char` (the `t` of import).
It puts everything out, and the output is allright. But the marking still doesn't work.
Does someone has a reason, why this could happen??

My Code for creating the Text widget and adding the tag:

```
def createWidgets(self):
    self.code = tkinter.Text(self)
    self.code.tag_configure("BLUE", foreground="blue")
```

my code for the thread:

```
def startT(self):
    for i in range(5):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.markup)
        t.start()
```

my markup code:

```
def markup(self):
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        #print("Getting code..")
        currentline = 0
        for line in self.code.get("1.0","end").splitlines():
            currentline += 1
            content = line.split(" ")
            for word in content:
                if word == "import":
                    try:
                        self.code.tag_add("BLUE", getBegin(currentline, line, word), getEnd(currentline, line, word))
                        print("Set \""+word+"\" from "+getBegin(currentline, line, word)+" TO "+getEnd(currentline, line, word)+ " to BLUE!")
                    except tk.TclError:
                        pass
                else:
                    try:
                        self.code.tag_add("BLACK", getBegin(currentline, line, word), getEnd(currentline, line, word))
                        print("Set \""+word+"\" from "+getBegin(currentline, line, word)+" TO "+getEnd(currentline,line,word)+" to BLACK!")
                    except tk.TclError:
                        pass
```

and at the end my codes for getting the position:

```
def getBeginEnd(line, word):
    buffer = 0
    for inline in line.split(" "):
        if inline != word:
             buffer += len(inline)+1
        else:
            return str(buffer)

def getBegin(currentline, line, word):
    return str(currentline)+"."+getBeginEnd(line,word)

def getEnd(currentline, line, word):
    return str(currentline)+"."+str(int(getBeginEnd(line,word))+len(word))
```

Comment: provide screenshots of how it looks.

Comment: Please don’t link to code on another site. Take the time to create a [mcve].